# How to dump GET/POST variable in ruby on rails with haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I want to create a debug section in my application and I need to dump all variables in the bottom of every page. I am new to `Haml` and I don't know how can I dump `GET` and `POST` variables. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using default layout of Rails when create new Rails app, so you will have a file in `app/views/layouts` named `application.haml`. Then you can append this to last line of body section:

```
= params
```

So `application.haml` should look like this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title SMAC Challenge
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render partial: 'shared/nav_bar'
    .container-fluid
      .flash= render partial: 'shared/flash_message', flash: flash
      .content
        = yield
      = render partial: 'shared/footer'
    = params
```

After that, all pages rendered within this layout (`application.haml`) will have all variables in the bottom.